# Issue with Lambda's capture clause

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use ftw function to calculate size of a directory. The prototype of ftw function is:

```
int ftw(const char *dirpath,
        int (*fn) (const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
                   int typeflag),
        int nopenfd);
```

To calculate the size of the entire directory, I am trying to use below code using lambda expression:

```
uint32_t calcDirSize(const char *path) {
   uint32_t usize = 0;

   if (ftw(path, [&usize](const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag) {
                     usize += sb->st_size;
                     return 0;
             }, 1)) {
    return 0;
   }

   return usize;
}
```

It is throwing error for the variable in the capture clause of the lambda expression. I want to use a local variable to calculate the size and return from calcDirSize function once it is calculated.
Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: The signature of your function is invalid to bind a lambda as the second parameter. What you need there is a *free function*, or (1) make your function a template, or (2) pass an std::function there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda is only convertable to a function-pointer if it is stateless, or in other words does not capture anything.

You are only allowed to use variables outside of the lambda without a capture if they have static storage duration.

```
uint32_t calcDirSize(const char *path) {
   static uint32_t usize = 0;
   usize = 0; // Make sure it's reset to 0 every time the function is called.


   if (ftw(path, [](const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag) {
                     usize += sb->st_size;
                     return 0;
             }, 1)) {
    return 0;
   }

   return usize;
}
```

By making `usize` static we can remove the capture in the lambda, and that makes it convertable to a function pointer.

**Edit:** As pointed in the comments this is not thread-safe as multiple calls to `calcDirSize` could modify/read `usize` at the same time.

Comment: You may want to note that this is **not** thread safe and suffers a performance hit since the compiler checks if the variable has been initialized in every call.

Comment: Very true, added a disclaimer.